# Merging very large csv files with common column

Tags: perl, unix, join, csv, awk

For example, I have two csv files, 
0.csv

```
100a,a,b,c,c
200a,b,c,c,c
300a,c,d,c,c
```

and
1.csv

```
100a,Emma,Thomas
200a,Alex,Jason
400a,Sanjay,Gupta
500a,Nisha,Singh
```

and I want an output to be like

```
100a,a,b,c,c,Emma,Thomas
200a,b,c,c,c,Alex,Jason
300a,c,d,c,c,0,0
400a,0,0,0,0,Sanjay,Gupta
500a,0,0,0,0,Nisha,Singh
```

How do I do that in Unix shell script or Perl? I know the unix "join" command, and that would work well with the small files. For example to get my result I could just do

```
join -t , -a 1 -a 2 -1 1 -2 1 -o 0 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 2.2 2.3 -e "0" 0.csv 1.csv
```

but that is not feasible for my purposes, since my actual data file has more than a million columns (total data size in the gigabytes), and thus my unix command would also be more than a million characters long. This might be the most important headache, as inefficient code gets bogged down quite fast.

Also note that I need the placeholder character "0" whenever there is missing data. This prevents me from simply using this

```
join -t , -a 1 -a 2 -1 1 -2 1 0.csv 1.csv
```

Also a beginner Perl programmer, so some details really welcome. I'd prefer the solution to be perl or shell script, but really anything that works would be fine.

Comment: How do you recognize when data is missing? (Not the down voter btw).

Comment: The total number of rows should be the total number of unique "ID" elements, and the total number of columns is the sum of the columns for the two files (minus one of course for the index column). So when "400a" is missing from the first file, then we have four "0" as placeholder, and when "300a" is missing from the second file, another two "0" is present in the output. Ever row should have the same number of elements, and the same goes for every row.

Comment: In your expected output, should `300a,c,c,c,c,0,0` be `300a,c,d,c,c,0,0` ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for spotting that. @steve

Answer (score 2):

If you can add a header to each file, then you could use [tabulator](https://github.com/stefan-schroedl/tabulator) to solve the problem. Example:

0.csv:

```
key,letter_1,letter_2,letter_3,letter_4
100a,a,b,c,c
200a,b,c,c,c
300a,c,d,c,c
```

1.csv:

```
key,name_1,name_2
100a,Emma,Thomas
200a,Alex,Jason
400a,Sanjay,Gupta
500a,Nisha,Singh
```

Then `tbljoin -lr -n 0 0.csv 1.csv` produces

```
key,letter_1,letter_2,letter_3,letter_4,name_1,name_2
100a,a,b,c,c,Emma,Thomas
200a,b,c,c,c,Alex,Jason
300a,c,d,c,c,0,0
400a,0,0,0,0,Sanjay,Gupta
500a,0,0,0,0,Nisha,Singh
```

Note that (in contrast to pure unix `join` command), the input files don't need to be sorted; also, you don't need to worry about memory consumption, since the implementation is based on unix sort, and will resort to file-based merge sort for large files.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with `awk`.

Determine the length of the widest row in both files and save it to `max0` and `max1`:

```bash
awk -F, '
  ARGIND == 1 && NF > max0 { max0 = NF }
  ARGIND == 2 && NF > max1 { max1 = NF }
  END { print max0, max1 }
' 0.csv 1.csv | read max0 max1
```

Use this awk script to do the join:

**foo.awk**

```awk
BEGIN { 
  max1--
  FS  = OFS = ","
}

ARGIND == 1 {
  A[$1] = $2

  # Copy columns from first file to key
  for(i=3; i<=NF; i++)
    A[$1] = A[$1] FS $i

  # Pad until we have max0 columns
  for( ; i<=max0; i++)
    A[$1] = A[$1] FS "0"
}

ARGIND == 2 {
  # Pad rows which are only in second file
  if(A[$1] == "") {
    A[$1] = 0
    for(i=3; i<=max0; i++)
      A[$1] = A[$1] FS "0"
  }

  # Copy columns from second file to key
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)
    A[$1] = A[$1] FS $i

  # Pad until we have max1 columns
  for( ; i<=max1; i++)
    A[$1] = A[$1] FS "0"
}

END { 
  for(key in A) {
    # Pad rows which are only in first file
    split(A[key], fields, ",")
    for(i=1; i <= max0+max1-length(fields)-1; i++)
      A[key] = A[key] FS "0"

    # Finally print key and accumulated column values
    print key, A[key]
  }
}
```

Run with:

```bash
awk -f foo.awk -v max0=$max0 -v max1=$max1 0.csv 1.csv | sort -n
```

Passing in the widest row values with `-v`. Output comes from a hash and is unsorted, so `sort -n` before displaying.

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with big amount of data and both sources has approximately same size, the merge join is the best choice. It's because once both (each) sources are sorted it uses a constant amount of memory. Merge join is also a good choice for full outer join and it can be written pretty elegantly in Perl.

For using following Perl script you have to have both files sorted in lexicographical order by key in the first column, and the key has to be unique. It also assumes there is the exactly same number of columns in each row in both files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

die "Usage $0 file1.csv file2.csv" unless @ARGV > 1;

my ( $file1, $file2 ) = @ARGV;

open my $fh1, '<', $file1 or die "Can't open $file1: $!";
open my $fh2, '<', $file2 or die "Can't open $file2: $!";

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } );

my $r1 = $csv->getline($fh1) or die "Missing data in $file1";
my $r2 = $csv->getline($fh2) or die "Missing data in $file2";

# same amount of zeros as number of fields in each file
my @cols1 = (0) x ( @$r1 - 1 );
my @cols2 = (0) x ( @$r2 - 1 );

while ( $r1 || $r2 ) {    # there are some data

    # compare keys only if there are rows in both files
    # zero silences warnings in numeric comparisons below
    my $cmp = $r1 && $r2 && ( $$r1[0] cmp $$r2[0] ) || 0;

    # row is defined and has less or equal key than another one
    my $le1 = $r1 && $cmp < 1;
    my $le2 = $r2 && $cmp > -1;

    $csv->print(
        *STDOUT,
        [   $le1 ? $$r1[0] : $$r2[0],    # key
            ( $le1 ? @$r1[ 1 .. @cols1 ] : @cols1 ),    # first file fields
            ( $le2 ? @$r2[ 1 .. @cols2 ] : @cols2 )     # second file fields
        ]
    );

    #read next rows
    $r1 = $csv->getline($fh1) if $le1;
    $r2 = $csv->getline($fh2) if $le2;
}
```

Usage is `script.pl 0.csv 1.csv > result.csv`. Use `sort -u -d -t,  -k1,1` for sorting of files if not sorted.

The script works in linear time (when already sorted) and uses memory only for storing one line from each file i.e. "constant" size.

You can sort files from your script using

```
$ENV{LC_ALL} = 'C';
open my $fh1, "( sed '1!d' $file1; sed 1d $file1 | sort -u -d -t, -k1,1 ) |"
    or die "Can't sort $file1: $!";
open my $fh2, "( sed '1!d' $file2; sed 1d $file2 | sort -u -d -t, -k1,1 ) |"
    or die "Can't sort $file2: $!";
```

Answer (score -1):

If your files are small enough to fit into the RAM, this should be easy. You can use Perl to read the files, parse them, and push the rows into a hash of arrays using the value in the common row as the hash key. 
Then iterate over the contents of the hash by its keys and print out the arrays.

Comment: It is clearly stated in question that *total data size in the gigabytes*.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I came up with(perl):

```
my $output={};

open FILE1, '</path/to/file1';
while (<FILE1>){
    chomp;
    my @values=split(/,/, $_);
    my $id=shift(@values);
    if($output->{$id}){
        my $temparray=$output->{$id};
        push (@$temparray, @values);
    }else{
        $output->{$id}=@values;
    }
}
close FILE1;
open FILE2, '</path/to/file2';
while (<FILE2>){
    chomp;
    my @values=split(/,/, $_);
    my $id=shift(@values);
    if($output->{$id}){
        my $temparray=$output->{$id};
        push (@$temparray, @values);
    }else{
        $output->{$id}=@values;
    }   
}
close FILE2;
```

Comment: Type of arg 1 to push must be array (not hash element) at mage.pl line 9, near "@values)"
Type of arg 1 to push must be array (not hash element) at mage.pl line 21, near "@values)"

Comment: hmm, this time nothing happens at all. Maybe I am a noob and misunderstood the code. So I am supposed to change '</path/to/file2' to the one I am using (for example, '</home/data/0.csv') or am I totally misunderstanding?

Comment: `/path/to/file1` would be `/home/data/0.csv` and `/path/to/file2` would be `/home/data/1.csv`

Comment: 1/ Reading whole data in memory is bad idea when *total data size in the gigabytes*.
2/ Parsing data in CSV using only split is bad idea when there are modules like Text::CSV.

Answer (score -1):

[`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/#) is a tool that handles csv files and allows such joins (among other features).

see [`csvjoin`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/scripts/csvjoin.html). Its command line interface is compact and it handles the multitude of csv formats (tsv, other delimiters, encodings, escape chars etc.)

What you asked for can be done using:

```
csvjoin --columns 0 0.csv 1.csv
```

Comment: It is not clear how achieve this specific task using this specific tool.

Comment: It doesn't work. There is required `--outer` according to question. There is not also clean how to define default value for missing rows in each file. Did you even tried to solve it with example data?